# Scraping data from Bureau of Labor Statistics website

Tags: python, python-2.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently scraping this website [Bureau of Labor Statistics](http://bls.gov/ooh) and I just want some feedback on how my approach was. I'm mainly focusing on the occupation groups table to the left of the website and the content inside those links. It would be great if you could give me feedback on my code and how it could be improved.

The code below is my table scraper which scrapes the tables.

```
class TableScraper(object):

    def __init__(self, html, classIdentifier, idName, linkFileName=None, dataFileName=None):
        # run BeautifulSoup on the html
        try:
            self.soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        except:
            self.soup = html
        self.requests_objects = []
        # class or id of the table
        self.classIdentifier = classIdentifier
        # class or id name of the table
        self.idName = idName
        # file names
        self.linkFileName = linkFileName
        self.dataFileName = dataFileName

    def scrapeHeader(self, classIdentifier, idName):
        # scrape the header of table
        # find table
        table = self.soup.find('table', attrs={''+classIdentifier+'' : ''+idName+''}) 
        if table is None:
            table = self.soup
        else:
            pass
        header = ''
        try:
            # find header
            header = table.find('thead').find('tr')
        except:
            header = table.find('tbody').find('tr')
        # loop through each row
        count = 0
        # list to hold headers
        header_list = []
        # get the headers
        for head in header:
            try:
                title = ''
                try:
                    # get title of header
                    title = head.text.encode('utf-8')
                except:
                    # move on to the next loop if we can't find the title
                    continue
                # set length of array
                colspan = 0
                # try to find length
                try:
                    colspan = int(head.get('colspan'))
                except:
                    # if we can find it set it to one
                    colspan = 1
                # set an array
                array = []
                for header in header_list:
                    array.append(header.requests_objects)
                header = TableHeader(colspan, title, count, array)
                self.requests_objects.append(header.findIndexes())
                count += 1
                print header.requests_objects
                header_list.append(header)
            except Exception as e:
                print e
        return header_list

    def init_list_of_objects(self, size):
        list_of_objects = list()
        for i in range(0,size):
            list_of_objects.append( list() ) # different object reference each time
        return list_of_objects

    def scrapeContent(self, header_list, classIdentifier, idName):
        # find table
        table = self.soup.find('table', attrs={''+classIdentifier+'' : ''+idName+''})
        if table is None:
            table = self.soup
        else:
            pass
        # scrape the contents of the header
        contents = table.find('tbody')
        rows = contents.find_all('tr')
        num_rows = 0
        # return array
        return_array = self.init_list_of_objects(len(self.requests_objects))
        for row in rows:
            num_rows += 1
            # array to store all of our data
            children = []
            # for item in row:
            items = row.find_all('td')
            print items[0].nextSibling
            # recursive loop to find a element with text
            for item in items:
                print str(len(items)) + "this"
                nextNode = item
                while True:
                    # get he next 
                    nextNode = nextNode.findNext()
                    try:
                        # try getting a text attribute 
                        nextNode.text
                    except AttributeError:
                        # if there is a error
                        pass
                    else:
                        # if we found the text
                        children.append(nextNode)
                        break
                print len(children)
            # set count s
            print str(children) + 'sparta'
            print str(num_rows) + "rows"
            count = 0
            # after appending them to children we add to return array
            for num_array in self.requests_objects:
                append_array = []
                for num in num_array:
                    print str(num) + 'num'
                    try:
                        append_array.append(str(children[num].text.encode('utf-8')).strip())
                    except Exception as e:
                        print e
                        print 'we could not fit it in header_list'
                return_array[count].append(append_array)
                count += 1
            print return_array
        return return_array

    def combineArrays(self, arrays):
        print "incombinearrays"
        # create a variable of the length of the arrays
        length_of_all_arrays = 0
        for array in arrays:
            for array2 in arrays:
                length_of_all_arrays = len(array.children)
                len(array.children) == len(array2.children)
                print("okay")
        # set an empty array of slots for future functions
        occupations = self.init_list_of_objects(length_of_all_arrays) #[None] * len(header_list[0].children)  # Create list of 100 'None's
        print str(len(occupations)) + " length"
        # check if we have the same amount
        print str(len(arrays)) + ' len of arrays'
        for array in arrays:
            count = 0 
            print len(array.children)
            for child in array.children:
                print str(count) + "count"
                child_index = array.children.index(child)
                print str(child_index) + 'index'
                occupations[count].append(child)
                count += 1
        for array in arrays:
            print str(array.children) + array.title
            print len(array.children)
        print len(occupations)
        for occupation in occupations:
            print occupation
        # print str(occupations[9]) + 'hi'
        return arrays, occupations

    def getLinks(self, classIdentifier, idName):
        # find table
        table = self.soup.find('table', attrs={''+classIdentifier+'' : ''+idName+''})
        if table is None:
            table = self.soup
        else:
            pass
        # scrape the contents of the header
        contents = table.find('tbody')
        link_header = contents.find_all('h4')
        # list of all the occupations
        occupation_links = []
        for header in link_header:
            # get a element which contains the link
            atag = header.find('a')
            link = atag['href']
            # get the title
            title = atag.text
            # create the blslink object
            blslink = BLSLink(self.url, link)
            # add title
            blslink.addChild(title)
            # append object to the array
            occupation_links.append(blslink)
        return occupation_links

    def jsonData(self, header_list=None, occupations=None):
        json_occupations_data = []
        json_links_data = []
        # write it to a json file
        for occupation in occupations:
            json_array = []
            for header in header_list:
                json_data = {
                    header.title : occupation[header_list.index(header)]
                }
                json_array.append(json_data)
            json_occupations_data.append(json_array)

        # write links to a json file
        links = self.getLinks(self.classIdentifier, self.idName)
        for link in links:
            json_links_data.append(link.createjson())
        print json_occupations_data
        return json_occupations_data, json_links_data

    def writeToJSON(self, array):
        for data in array:
            filename = ''+data.file+''
            f = open(filename, "w")
            jsonstuff = json.dumps(data.data, indent=4)
            f.write(jsonstuff)
        # # write it in json file
        # filename = ''+dataFileName+''
        # f = open(filename, "w")
        # jsonstuff = json.dumps(json_occupations_data, indent=4)
        # f.write(jsonstuff)

        # filename = ''+linkFileName+''
        # f = open(filename, "w")
        # json_data = json.dumps(json_links_data, indent=4)
        # f.write(json_data)

    def scrape(self):
        headers = self.scrapeHeader(self.classIdentifier, self.idName)
        contents = self.scrapeContent(headers, self.classIdentifier, self.idName)
        count = 0
        for content in contents:
            headers[count].addChild(content)
            count += 1
        header_list, occupations = self.combineArrays(headers)
        json_occupations_data, json_links_data = self.jsonData(header_list, occupations)
        BLSData = namedtuple('BLSData', 'data file')
        content1 = BLSData(json_occupations_data, self.dataFileName)
        print str(json_occupations_data) + "hi and stuff"
        content2 = BLSData(json_links_data, self.linkFileName)
        return [content1, content2]
```

The code below is the code which calls the class. The link file contains a bunch of links which leads to the careers in the occupation.

```
# make program look like a browser, user_agent
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5 (Solaris 10) Gecko'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
# search keys
search_urls = []
# get json file name 
jsonfilename = "links.json"
# open json file as var json_data
with open(jsonfilename) as json_data:
    # store it in variable d
    d = json.load(json_data)
    # get second object
    for link in d:
        for child in link:
            title = link[child]
            for url in title:
                blslink = title[url]
                search_urls.append(blslink)
# set the url we want to scrape
search_url = search_urls[9]
# get webdriver and call phantomjs
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(''+search_url+'')

# waiting for the page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# find an element
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "wrapper-outer")))
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sorting")
# simulate a click on the button
link.click()
# get the page source of the website
html = driver.page_source
```

I have another piece of code which scrapes the last page when you click an occupation from the table of careers.

```
# scrape occupations
# make program look like a browser, user_agent
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5 (Solaris 10) Gecko'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
# search keys
search_urls = []
# get json file name 
jsonfilename = "occupationlinks.json"
# open json file as var json_data
with open(jsonfilename) as json_data:
    # store it in variable d
    d = json.load(json_data)
    # get second object
    for link in d:
        for child in link:
            title = link[child]
            for url in title:
                blslink = title[url]
                search_urls.append(blslink)

search_url = search_urls[1]
page = urllib.urlopen(search_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')
contents = soup.find('div', attrs={'id' : 'panes'})
occupation_info = []
for content in contents:
    article = content.find("article")
    try: 
        for items in article:
            continue
    except:
        continue
    for items in article:
        # to keep track if we added a class or not
        addedContainer = False
        try:
            # print items
            # loop all types of headers
            for i in range(1,7):
                # if node is a h tag
                if items.name == 'h'+str(i):
                    # make a new blscontainer object
                    title = items.text
                    # give it a new title
                    new_container = BLSContent(title)
                    # add the new container to the temp container
                    occupation_info.append(new_container)
                    # append the text of the title and break the loop
                    addedContainer = True
                    break
            # if its content add it
            if addedContainer == False:
                # if the element is a table
                if items.name == 'table':
                    print items.get('class')[0]
                    table_scraper = TableScraper(search_url, items,     'class', items.get('class')[0], linkFileName=None, dataFileName=None)
                    scraped_data = table_scraper.scrape()
                    print str(scraped_data[0].data) + "asdf"
                    occupation_info[-1].addChild(scraped_data[0].data)
                    break
                # get last appended container and add to it
                occupation_info[-1].addChild(items.text)
        except Exception as e:
            print str(e) + "error is"
print occupation_info[7].children
jsonstuff = []
for info in occupation_info:
    json_data = {
        info.title : info.children
    }
    jsonstuff.append(json_data)
json_data = json.dumps(jsonstuff, indent=4)
filename = "info.json"
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write(json_data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Error handling?

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me:

> ```
> try:
>     self.soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
> except:
>     self.soup = html
> ```

This looks like the code expects the `html` parameter to be either of two things:

- An HTML document that can be parsed by `BeautifulSoup`
- A `BeautifulSoup` instance

I find this a confusing API.
It may seem like nice "magic" that the code will work whatever you throw at it,
but it would be cleaner and better to have different API to handle the different kinds of inputs.
The API that handles html can internally call the other one that handles `BeautifulSoup` instances.

#### String conversion

I don't understand the purpose of the `''+...+''` here:

> ```
> table = self.soup.find('table', attrs={''+classIdentifier+'' : ''+idName+''}) 
> if table is None:
>     table = self.soup
> else:
>     pass
> ```

If you want convert `foo` to string, use `str(foo)`, for example `str(classIdentifier)`.

If `classIdentifier` is already a string, then prepending an empty string and appending an empty string is completely pointless.

Also, the `else: pass` is pointless, it's better to omit it.

#### Use list comprehensions

This is a perfect candidate for using list comprehensions:

> ```
> # set an array
> array = []
> for header in header_list:
>     array.append(header.requests_objects)
> ```

Like this:

```
headers = [header.requests_objects for header in header_list]
```

I also renamed the variables, because there are no arrays in Python.

Another example:

> ```
> list_of_objects = list()
> for i in range(0,size):
>     list_of_objects.append( list() ) # different object reference each time
> return list_of_objects
> ```

Using a list comprehension:

```
# different object reference each time
return [list() for _ in range(size)]
```

#### Strange code

This looks strange, and I doubt it works as intended:

> ```
> length_of_all_arrays = 0
> for array in arrays:
>     for array2 in arrays:
>         length_of_all_arrays = len(array.children)
>         len(array.children) == len(array2.children)
>         print("okay")
> ```

For one thing,
the statement `len(array.children) == len(array2.children)` is pointless.
For another,
`length_of_all_arrays` is overwritten for each value in `arrays`.
This would make more sense, but it's hard to tell what your real intention was here:

```
length_of_all_arrays = [len(a.children) for a in arrays]
```